# Profiles and Image Formula Fields

Tags: formula-field, image-formula, user-profile

I had to create a profile that was significantly more restricted than any of our other profiles. In the process of creating this profile, I have ended up causing an important formula field with an image to only display the **alt text**. Does anyone know where to change this on the Profile permissions?

Already tried...
Enabling Read on Documents and Assets. But still can't determine which profile setting would prevent this from working correctly.

Comment: Can you share the formula field? Does it definitely point to files that are stored in Documents or Assets?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We figured out. Thanks for your comments about the Libraries. We aren't sure if there was an update to make our logos stop working, because they actually stopped working on our current users suddenly.

Either way, it's not enough to actually have an image file in Salesforce. You have to upload that asset to a library, and during that flow it will allow you to select an option for internal users. [Here is the documentation on it](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=admin_files_asset_files_create.htm&type=5):

Answer (score 0):

You can try to add "Access Libraries" in administrative permissions.

Also, be sure that your asset or your library is shared to this profile. On the App Launcher, navigate to files and then share assets and libraries that contains those images with your new profile.

Comment: This feature was already there. Shared the file with the user that has the profile, but still no dice. Any other suggestions?

Comment: Another thought, if you uploaded those images on classic salesforce, at the time, you might need to share the folder containing them. Switch to salesforce classic, navigate to "document" and share folders to your profile.

Comment: our salesforce instance has never been on classic. Will take a look though, but I'm not sure that it would apply...